# iOS app view background (Image vs draw) design question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Suppose I was writing a game which involved a relatively complex geometric game board. Something like a dartboard.

I would want a view to display the game state. What is the best way to implement that view?

For example, should I draw the board off line in something like photoshop, add it as a resource, and then show it using a UIImageView? Or should I use drawing primitives and essentially draw the board programmatically?

What are the trade-offs?

If I do use an image, what format should I prefer? .png, .tiff, .gif, .jpg?

Thanks,
John

Comment: This isn't really a full answer, but re: the image format, always prefer png format. It's lossless compression so you get a nice, compact file size but without any artifacts plus the phone has hardware decoder for it so while it's not exactly cheap to initialize, it's much cheaper than the other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to go the image route you should use png. Displaying any other format you pay a performance hit (as mentioned in the comment).

To decide between building photoshop vs drawing via code you need to decide how much time you want to put into learning Quartz/CoreGraphics. Apple's docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

If you already know Photoshop then building the graphic there is probably much easier, if you don't then learning Quartz is prob a less steep learning curve than Photoshop...

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple board, it's easy enough to draw it into the view, which gives you the possibility of easily manipulating it in interesting ways. Drawing in a view is done with a set of postscript like primitives.

For something more fancy, photoshop might be the way to go.

PNGs are preferred.